# Application not responding in child thread

Tags: android, multithreading, download, android-anr-dialog

I want to download a video from the internet in my application. Hence, I started a new thread and in that thread I started a service which downloads the file. However, it throws application not responding dialog on the emulator but downloads the file in the background. I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution. Please help!

My thread is as below:

```
    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Log.i("Test Log", "Starting Service");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DownloadService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

and snippet of service is below:

```
try
     {
        Log.i("Test log", "Entered function");

        String RootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Video";
        File RootFile = new File(RootDir);
        RootFile.mkdir();

        URL u = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        long fileSize = c.getContentLength();
        Log.e("Test log", "File Size is: " +String.valueOf(fileSize));

        String downloadedFile = RootFile + "/Sample.mp4";
        Log.i("Test Log", downloadedFile);
        File df = new File(downloadedFile);

        if(fileSize == df.length())
        {
            Log.i("Test log", "File exists already! Did not download");
            stopSelf();
        }
        else
        {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(RootFile, fileName));
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();

            Log.i("Test log", "Downloaded and file saved as "+downloadedFile);
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Catch exception", "Error is " +e.toString());
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The below is the crash log:

```
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60): ANR in com.pranav.download
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60): Reason: Executing service com.pranav.download/.DownloadService
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60): Load: 0.49 / 0.21 / 0.17
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60): CPU usage from 723800ms to 49ms ago:
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   system_server: 5% = 4% user + 1% kernel /   faults: 3616 minor 2 major
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   adbd: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel / faults:  1593 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   qemud: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 18 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 869 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   d.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1143 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   id.defcontainer: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 64 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   com.svox.pico: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 28 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   rild: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   com.android.mms: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   m.android.email: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   netd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   .quicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
    06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   android.protips: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
   06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   ackageinstaller: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 16 minor
   06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 35 minor
   06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   installd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
   06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):   m.android.music: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
   06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):  +pranav.download: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
   06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60):  +pranav.download: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
   06-14 17:32:32.638: E/ActivityManager(60): TOTAL: 14% = 6% user + 7% kernel + 0% irq + 0% softirq
```

Comment: Do you use an `IntentService`?

Comment: @Luksprog I as of now use Service. Tried IntentService too. The same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `async task handler`...so that the main thread will not be interrupted and the downloading would be carried out in the background...If you need a example..please let me know..
use this link [Async tasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I wanted the download service to kill itself after operation. That was the reason I used stopSelf and tried IntentService and not used AsyncTask. Is it possible in AsyncTask? or is there a way to kill AsyncTask after the operation is done? I am killing it because, I will be calling the same service multiple number of times in the app and dont want to raise an error by not creating the download coz the service is already running.

Answer (score 0):

You may have started the service from another thread but it will run code on the UI thread.

In your service put the code to download the video in the `doInBackground(...)` method of an `AsyncTask` e.g.

```
new AsyncTask< Void, Void, Void >() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground( final Void... params )
    {
        // Your download code
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not sure whether the thread will be started again if it is already running and hence, I want to kill the thread which is downloading coz I want to call it multiple times in the application. Hence, I used stopSelf in the thread and used IntentService. 

Does another AsyncTask activity start even if the previously called one is running in the background? Or, is there a way to kill it so that it wont create problems later?